# Visio VBA Return the 'Start' and 'End' of shape as values related to the Horizontal Ruler

Tags: vba, properties, shapes, visio

I have a Visio drawing (and will have many more) that have a timeline e.g. months or quarters represented by boxes
[Example 'timeline'][1]

The drawing will have shapes that align to the 'timeline' and I need to read through the shapes and return the Shape Text and the Start and End ruler positions of shapes - from this I can ascribe a date and duration of sorts which is consumable elsewhere.  I have failed to find a means by which to find Start and End positions of shapes that I can relate (consistently) to the ruler (or the shape timeline 'boxes').

The obvious, PinX and PinY values are not consistent (in relation to the ruler or other shapes).  I have no control over the received drawings -so the ruler is the only constant.

Any help would be appreciated (whilst not at all new to VBA I am new to Visio VBA and there is a lot to it and a lot I do not understand).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMzC3.png

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Please show us the code you have so far - otherwise it is hard to help you. Please read [ask] and [repro]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was me, much as I hate to admit it.  With all items Pin Pos Centre-Centre and LocPinX = width*0.5 this works.  The actual measurement of the Ruler is irrelevant as the shapes do follow consistent positioning so that 'Start X' = PinX-(width/2) OR PinX - LocPinX and therefore 'EndX' = 'Start X' + Width.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).